# Keep nodes in the background

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

Im working on a project were i generate random circles at the background so i can grow them and let them disappear and do this process over and over (for a trip effect) but when i do this the circles overlap all my other nodes. 
is it possible to keep them on the background?

i use this code to generate my circles

```
let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.TripEffects()})
        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
        let sequense = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
        let Loop = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequense)
        self.runAction(Loop)


func TripEffects() {
    // Create Random RGB color
        var red = Float(arc4random_uniform(100)+1)
        red = red / 100
        var green = Float(arc4random_uniform(100)+1)
        green = green / 100
        var blue = Float(arc4random_uniform(100)+1)
        blue = blue / 100
    //define a circle
    let TripCircle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 1)
    //set the colors
    TripCircle.fillColor = SKColor( red:   CGFloat(red),green: CGFloat(green),
                                    blue:  CGFloat(blue),alpha: 1)
    //set the posiotion
    TripCircle.position = CGPoint (x: CGFloat(arc4random()%(canvasWidth)),
                                    y: CGFloat(arc4random()%(canvasHeight)))
    // add the node to the scene
        self.addChild(TripCircle)

     //set the Animation
    let Grow = SKAction.scaleTo(100, duration: 10)
    let Hide = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0, duration: 1)
    let Remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let Sequence = SKAction.sequence([Grow, Hide, Remove])

     TripCircle.runAction(Sequence)
 }
```

Comment: A node's zPosition allows you to override the default draw order. A node with a smaller z value will be behind a node with a larger value. The default value is zero.

Comment: Set the zPosition of the circles to a lower value than all the other needs which need to stay on top.

Comment: thanks TripCircle.zPosition = -1 worked for me

Comment: @0x141E please add an answer to this question and have it accepted by Basile.